# Random value created in embedded JavaScript, how do I return this into my LoadRunner script?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am currently creating a script that has an embedded JavaScript file which creates a random value which is causing my script to fail, I've found the function which creates this within the .js file. Is there a way of capturing/returning the generated value from this into my script?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There are many ways.  You can reproduce the algorithm in C.  Or, you can execute the JavaScript function from within your web virtual user.   I prefer to convert to C, but that is not the path for all.

Boris Kozorovitzky, from the HP LoadRunner R&D team,
has a great article on just this topic, located at

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-use-JavaScript-in-your-HP-LoadRunner-scripts/ba-p/6197321#.VZvDXRNVhHw

Enjoy!